# Renaming: How to attach a word or rename multiple files

Tags: bash, rename

I have multiple files in my directory.
for example:

```
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-22
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-23
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-01
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-02
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-03
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-04
```

and I want to change all of them to

```
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-22
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-23
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-01
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-02
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-03
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-04
```

How can I use mv command to perform this task ?
I have use this

```
mv  eventDataLog.txt.2015-* ec2prod-eventDataLog.txt.2015-*
mv: target ‘ec2prod-eventDataLog.txt.2015-*’ is not a directory
```

but do not works

but remember I have many other files in that directory so answer would be appropraite and also I have to ignore this file eventDataLog.txt
because it is current file and in use.

Comment: What other files do you have?

Comment: Craig other files would be any like abc-date.txt
zcd-date.txt   and so on.

Comment: you are taking input from ls command but ls command includes other files also

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

Bash is good for this.

`for FILE in eventDataLog.txt.2015*; do mv "$FILE" "abc-$FILE"; done`

Comment: You should add some quotes to that command: `for FILE in eventDataLog.txt.2015*; do mv "$FILE" "abc-$FILE"; done` or `for FILE in eventDataLog.txt.2015*; do mv "$FILE" abc-"$FILE"; done`.

Comment: @kasperd True - while in this particular case there were no filenames with spaces, it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Missing one double quote after $FILE

Comment: It's OK to edit someone else's answer to fix things like this.

Comment: Theres many ways to skin a cat. I approve of the obvious-what-this-does approach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't edit an answer unless you change at least 4 characters or some minimum.  I've tried to correct typos before and it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @sa289 If I recall correctly, the limit is 6 characters and applies to users with less than 2000 reputation.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this using the `rename` comamnd.  In your case you'd do `rename eventDataLog.txt.2015 abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015 eventDataLog.txt*`.

The syntax it uses is `rename frompattern topattern listoffilessuchaswildcardmatch`.

Comment: now check again my question guys

Comment: sa289 your solution will change also my current file eventDataLog.txt but I want to ignore it.

Comment: Then simply do `rename eventDataLog.txt.2015 abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015 eventDataLog.txt*` so it's more specific on what it renames from and to.  If it doesn't find a match it won't rename.

Comment: That works with the `rename` command from Red Hat based distributions. Debian based distributions have a different `rename` command with a different syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `mmv` tool and do

```
mmv eventDataLog.txt.\* abc-eventDataLog.txt.\#1
```

which is specifically designed to do mass renames.

Answer (score 0):

### Command

```
for FILE in $(ls -1 | egrep '^eventDataLog' | egrep -v '^eventDataLog.txt$'); do mv $FILE abc-$FILE; done
```

### Notes

- `egrep` is the regex-capable version of `grep` and is included with `grep` in most distributions
- First `egrep` will filter all files starting with "eventDataLog"
- Second `egrep` will filter all files that **do not** (note `-v` noting an *inverse* match) match the full name of the file you wish to ignore

### Proof

```
$ ls -1
eventDataLog.txt
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-22
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-23
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-01
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-02
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-03
eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-04
myOtherFile
mySecondOtherFile

$ for FILE in $(ls -1 | egrep '^eventDataLog' | egrep -v '^eventDataLog.txt$'); do mv $FILE abc-$FILE; done

$ ls -1
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-22
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-23-23
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-01
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-02
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-03
abc-eventDataLog.txt.2015-04-24-04
eventDataLog.txt
myOtherFile
mySecondOtherFile
```

Comment: That solution works for this case, but I'd suggest the rename command is a better general solution as it can do renames even mid-filename.  I've posted an answer with an example.

Comment: but Craig there are a lots of file in that directory so it would not be work

Comment: Have you tried it? That solution works for the data you have given. If you need a different solution, edit your question and post better requirements.

Comment: There's no need to use `ls` - just use a fileglob to expand the filenames directly.

Comment: This is like going from Boston to San Francisco via Beirut.

Comment: normal grep can handle basic regular expressions - egrep can handle "extended" regular expressions.  (Anyone used to perl regexp will find the "extensions" quite sparse - check out pcregrep.)